# Should [super loadView] be called from loadView or not?

Tags: ios

In Programming iOS 4 by Matt Newburg he states:

> “To provide a `UIViewController` with a view manually, implement its
> `loadView` method… You must NOT call `super`”.

In the iOS 5 Developer's Cookbook by Erica Sadun she states:

> “The `loadView` method allows you to set up the screen and layout any
> subviews… Make sure to call `[super loadView]` whenever you inherit
> from a specialized subclass such as `UITableViewController` or
> `UITabBarController`.”

This, to me at least, is confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple is the source of truth and they say NO super call.

> If you override this method in order to create your views manually,
> you should do so and assign the root view of your hierarchy to the
> view property. (The views you create should be unique instances and
> should not be shared with any other view controller object.) Your
> custom implementation of this method should not call super.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview

[edit]

Another important note scattered around in the UIViewController class reference:

> The default loadView method attempts to load the view from the nib
> file associated with the view controller (if any).

Comment: Whoops. For some reason I thought they didn't state it specifically.

Comment: I've a short question about this. I've the AppDelegate and set it's rootView to another UIViewController Class instance (where I modify the view in loadView). If I don't call [super loadView] the method is called three times. If I call it, everything is perfect. So did I miss something in Apple's documentation?

If I'm not allowed to do [super loadView] where should I set up my view if I don't load the view from nib?

Comment: If I set a UINavigationController as the rootViewController to the app delegate and push the UIViewController onto the navcontroller stack again everything is perfect. So I don't understand why these differences occur.

Comment: But what is their rationale for this frankly befuddling guideline?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question, but I find that it needs a better answer than the one it got.

> Should `[super loadView]` be called from loadView or not?

**It depends.** The two sources you cite are talking about different situations, and they're both correct in the context they're describing.

The quote from Neuberg is talking about view controllers that inherit directly from `UIViewController`. That class has its own implementation of `loadView` that provides default behavior; specifically, it automatically loads the view hierarchy from a .xib (or storyboard) file that's associated with the view controller. If you call `UIViewController`'s version of that method, the view hierarchy created in that method will either replace your own implementation's view hierarchy, or vice versa. Nine years after this question was posed, [the documentation for `UIViewController`'s `-loadView` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview?language=objc) still warns against that:

> You can override this method in order to create your views manually. If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view hierarchy to the view property. The views you create should be unique instances and should not be shared with any other view controller object. **Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.** [emphasis added]

The quote from Sadun is talking about a *different situation*, i.e. one in which your view controller is not a direct subclass of `UIViewController`, but is instead derived from `UITableViewController`, `UITabBarController`, etc. Those classes override `-loadView` themselves and need their versions called. At least in the case of `UITableViewController`, this is called out in the [Overview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller?language=objc) section:

> You may override loadView or any other superclass method, but if you do, be sure to invoke the superclass implementation of the method, usually as the first method call.

So, if you're subclassing `UIViewController` and providing your own `-loadView` implementation to generate the controller's views rather than using a .xib or storyboard to provide the views, don't call the superclass's `-loadView` method. On the other hand, if you're subclassing a class such as `UITableView` and doing the same thing, check the docs to see whether you need to call that class's `-loadView` method from your own override.